# What Can I Use Instead of DOMSubtreeModified?

Tags: javascript, dom, opera, userscripts

I'm working on a user script for opera, and opera doesn't support [DOMSubtreeModified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified),
Is there any alternative method for subtree modified?

NOTE: I'm looking a solution only in javascript. (not jquery or any javascript library)

Thanks.

Comment: What percentage of your users actually use Opera? Consider the question: is it really worth it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Target the nodes you really care about, then use an interval timer to check for changes.

The key is choosing the nodes of interest, for example given:

```
<div id="content"><p class="author"> ... </p> 
... 
</div>
```

Maybe you want the "author" nodes.
You would scan for these using `querySelectorAll("#content p.author")` inside a timer.

Something like this **pseudo** code:

```
setInterval (MyNodeCheckFunc, 500);

function MyNodeCheckFunc () 
{
    var newNodeList     = [];
    this.oldNodeList    = this.oldNodeList  ||  [];

    var targetNodes     = document.querySelectorAll ('VALID CSS-STYLE SELECTOR');
    if (targetNodes  &&  targetNodes.length > 0) 
    {
        /*--- Found target node(s).  Go through each and act if they
            are new.
        */
        for (var J = targetNodes.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) 
        {
            var targNode = targetNodes[J];

            newNodeList.push (targNode);

            if (! targNode.weHaveProcessed) 
            {
                targNode.weHaveProcessed    = true;

                //// DO STUFF FOR NEW NODE.
            }
        }
    }

    /*/// HERE, COMPARE newNodeList TO oldNodeList.
        1)  If an item is in oldNodeList, but not in newNodeList, 
            do any DELETED NODE action.

        2)  If an item is in a different order from oldNodeList 
            to newNodeList, do any MOVED NODE action.
    */
    this.oldNodeList = newNodeList;
}
```