# How do I call a function every time the DOM changes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom, event-handling

I need to ensure that a page stays the way my script describes even after the DOM changes; my script has to handle these changes to the DOM such that my script doesn't only handle on the initial state.

Is there an event that I can use to handle these DOM changes?

Comment: Just a thought, but this sounds like a bad idea. Just think about it, if you managed to set up a function that is to be fired whenever the dom is changed, then inside that function you change the dom, you got neverending recursion.

Comment: Not clear what you want.  If you have a jQuery selector, you can use that `waitForKeyElements()` function to check for all additions.  If you car about deletions or content changes, that's not a hard mod.  You can also listen for `DOMSubtreeModified`, or similar, but that gets messy.

Comment: @Alxandr: Consider that I'm not changing the DOM inside that call, or disable the event in that call.

Comment: @SteveWellens: Because we are living in a Web 2.0 age?

Comment: @BrockAdams: Do you have any links on those? I can't find the first function you mentioned on Google...

Comment: `waitForKeyElements()` is the key function in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8283815/) (which I thought you used) and a few others.  `DOMSubtreeModified` is an event type.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Taking your question in the strictest sense, something like this:

```
//--- Narrow the container down AMAP.
$("YOUR SELECTOR").bind ("DOMSubtreeModified", HandleDOM_ChangeWithDelay);

var zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer = null;

function HandleDOM_ChangeWithDelay (zEvent) {
    if (typeof zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer == "number") {
        clearTimeout (zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer);
        zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer = '';
    }
    zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer     = setTimeout (HandleDOM_Change, 333);
}

function HandleDOM_Change () {
    // YOUR CODE HERE.
}
```

Note that you want the intermediate delay function because the changes will come in clusters of 10 to 100's of events on a site like Youtube or Google.

You only want to fire on the last event of a cluster -- that's when the change you care about is finished.

---

---

IMPORTANT:

It's been a while since I've used the `DOMSubtreeModified` approach, because it performs poorly in practice.  So, I forgot I had a utility function for it.

Also, as Raynos reminds, [**mutation events are deprecated**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#_34).  So, Firefox may stop supporting these events in some future release.

One other problem:  If your script also changes the nodes in the container you are monitoring, the script can get stuck in an infinite loop/recursion.

Here is the code to avoid the loop (and that global variable):

```
function HandleDOM_Change () {
    // YOUR CODE HERE.
}

//--- Narrow the container down AMAP.
fireOnDomChange ('YOUR JQUERY SELECTOR', HandleDOM_Change, 100);

function fireOnDomChange (selector, actionFunction, delay)
{
    $(selector).bind ('DOMSubtreeModified', fireOnDelay);

    function fireOnDelay () {
        if (typeof this.Timer == "number") {
            clearTimeout (this.Timer);
        }
        this.Timer  = setTimeout (  function() { fireActionFunction (); },
                                    delay ? delay : 333
                                 );
    }

    function fireActionFunction () {
        $(selector).unbind ('DOMSubtreeModified', fireOnDelay);
        actionFunction ();
        $(selector).bind ('DOMSubtreeModified', fireOnDelay);
    }
}
```

Comment: DOM manipulation events are deprecated. They should not be recommended.

Comment: @Raynos, Ironically, I don't.  But I'd already pointed the OP to a better way in another question.  He wanted this, and others might too.

Comment: But they should not use it because its deprecated. This means this code will break in the future and stop working. There should be a larger disclaimer saying "This will break in the future"

Comment: @Raynos: Fair enough; updated the answer. It needed a bit of practicality added also.

Comment: For the record, as an aside. [Mutations](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutations) are coming back in DOM4 but that's far from final and far from commonly implemented.

Comment: @Raynos, so if `DOMSubtreeModified` is **deprecated** ,what do you suggest instead?

Comment: @gdoron if you really need a way to run code when the dom changes, do it pre-emptively. i.e. before you change some part of the dom in your code, fire an event. If you must do it without modifying existing code the only thing you can do is periodically crawl the entire dom and manually check each node & attr for whether it has changed

Comment: @gdoron, Funny you should ask.  [A good old interval timer does the trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8168559/) especially if you also use jQuery `.data()`.

Comment: @Raynos, remember that this is a Greasemonkey question. We don't control the target page and have no practical way to fire events preemptively.

Comment: I didn't read the actual question.I just think requiring listening on dom changes either involves periodic polling for diffs or redesign. The question is far too vague to suggest a correct redesign

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about binding events on DOM elements which may not exist on document.ready, then you can use either [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind to any element that matches the provided selector, now or in the future.

Comment: These attach event handlers, can't I run code instead on those elements?