# onmove event equivalent in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the equivalent name for onmove in query. Here is what onmove does in straight javascript.

**IE support only:**

Occurs when the position of an element's top-left corner is changed.

Is there an event in jquery that does this.

Comment: What triggers the element's position change? Just link a function to that with a comment saying what it does.

Comment: if the element is moved after a drag event, you can use the "stop", "start" or "drag" events of JQuery-UI Draggable, if it is moved by any other even you could use the end of that event to be notified about the movement.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible using native event listener. However, you can put the function in the function that make the element move to achieve it.

For example:

```
<div id="box"></div>
<script>
    function blah(){
        //onmove things...
    }

    function movebox(e){
        blah(e);  //link to the function
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The position of an element relatively to the document may change due to a number of reasons - including edge cases like an HTML5-Video showing a smaller preview picture after watching, which is not covered by listening to click, keyup, reload and any other events.

Since jQuery does not have a built-in support for `onmove`, the best bet you can do, is catching many events that *could* move your element and then filter, whether your element did *really* move, which can be done by comparing the current [`jQuery.fn.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) value to the value it had on the last event appearance.

The both most important events that may move your element (page generation and window resizing) are covered by this solution:

```
jQuery(window).on('load resize', function () {
    /* code here... */
}
```

If your DOM might change, you can use this instead:

```
jQuery(window).on('load resize DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
    /* code here... */
}
```

But use the last one with care, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369097/how-do-i-call-a-function-every-time-the-dom-changes-in-jquery#8369269).

Becaues those events are called *very often*, it is important for your customers pc, that you do not perform any complicated tasks per event or at least check, that the position of your element did *really* change (as mentioned above).